# curl globbing - quit when fail possible?

Tags: curl, glob

If you are doing a globbed retrieval and do not know a priori how many pages there are to retrieve is it possible to have cURL quit once it hits a 404.

e.g curl --silent --request GET 'www.thesite.com/page=[1-50]'

but there are only 12 pages.

So you hit a 404 going for page 13. Anyway to make cURL abort further page retrieval?

Or is it something one would have to do programmitically?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding -f, according to the manual that will abort.

curl --fail --silent --request GET 'www.thesite.com/page=[1-50]'

Comment: Close. It's a definite upgrade. It stops curl from delivering html associated with the 404 but it still continues attempts after failure until it cycles the full extent of the glob.

Comment: Works for me with curl version 7.24.0. The command I used: `curl --silent --fail --request GET 'http://localhost:8000/foo[1-100].html'`

Comment: If you turn on verbose (curl --verbose) instead of silent you will see that it is actually attempting the subsequent calls. Silent stops them from appearing in the output but I think those calls are still made.